# Transform a rotation matrix to match another

Tags: eigen3, rotational-matrices

I have two 3x3 rotation matrices as:

```
Eigen::Matrix3d a;
a = Eigen::AngleAxisd(0.25*M_PI,   Eigen::Vector3d::UnitX())
  * Eigen::AngleAxisd(0.45*M_PI,   Eigen::Vector3d::UnitY())
  * Eigen::AngleAxisd(0.0,         Eigen::Vector3d::UnitZ());

Eigen::Matrix3d b;
a = Eigen::AngleAxisd(0.25*M_PI,   Eigen::Vector3d::UnitX())
  * Eigen::AngleAxisd(0.0,         Eigen::Vector3d::UnitY())
  * Eigen::AngleAxisd(0.25*M_PI,   Eigen::Vector3d::UnitZ());
```

I would like to find the 3x3 matrix `c` where `a*c = b`.

I calculate the angle axis of both rotations like this:

```
Eigen::AngleAxisd angleAxisA(a);
Eigen::AngleAxisd angleAxisB(b);
```

Now I know that I have an angle `a.angle()` and a `Vector3d` axis `a.axis()`.

From here I do not know what to do. Can someone suggest how I can go from here please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a 3x3 matrix. You can simply [invert it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix) to solve the equation system. `a*c = b --> c = a^-1 * b`.

```cpp
int main() {
  Eigen::Matrix3d a;
  a = Eigen::AngleAxisd(0.25*M_PI,   Eigen::Vector3d::UnitX())
    * Eigen::AngleAxisd(0.45*M_PI,   Eigen::Vector3d::UnitY())
    * Eigen::AngleAxisd(0.0,         Eigen::Vector3d::UnitZ());

  Eigen::Matrix3d b;
  b = Eigen::AngleAxisd(0.25*M_PI,   Eigen::Vector3d::UnitX())
    * Eigen::AngleAxisd(0.0,         Eigen::Vector3d::UnitY())
    * Eigen::AngleAxisd(0.25*M_PI,   Eigen::Vector3d::UnitZ());

  Eigen::Matrix3d c = a.inverse() * b;

  std::cout << "a:\n" << a << "\n\n"
            << "b:\n" << b << "\n\n"
            << "c:\n" << c << "\n\n"
            << "a * c = b:\n" << (a * c) << "\n";
}
```

```
a:
 0.156434         0  0.987688
 0.698401  0.707107 -0.110616
-0.698401  0.707107  0.110616

b:
   0.707107   -0.707107 5.55112e-17
        0.5         0.5   -0.707107
        0.5         0.5    0.707107

c:
   0.110616   -0.110616   -0.987688
   0.707107    0.707107 1.11022e-16
   0.698401   -0.698401    0.156434

a * c = b:
   0.707107   -0.707107 5.55112e-17
        0.5         0.5   -0.707107
        0.5         0.5    0.707107
```

> But is there a way to solve it using the AngleAxisd which I was trying to use?

Yes.

```cpp
Eigen::AngleAxisd angleAxisC {angleAxisA.inverse() * angleAxisB};
```

Mathematically, inverting an `AngleAxis` is simple enough (just negate the angle). But multiplying two `AngleAxis` is non-trivial. It converts to a [`Quaternion`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Quaternion.html) and multiplies those. The conversion involves transcendental function calls. Try to avoid needless conversions.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I want. But is there a way to solve it using the *AngleAxisd* which I was trying to use?

Comment: @ellat Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/624348/finding-rotation-axis-and-angle-to-align-two-oriented-vectors

Comment: @ellat or rather: `Eigen::AngleAxisd angleAxisC{angleAxisA.inverse() * angleAxisB}`

Comment: @ellat The math does a whole lot of conversions from and to quaternions if you look at the code. So I doubt it will be faster.

Comment: Unless you are interested in the 3x3 matrix representation, you can use quaternions all the time (just change the type of `a`, `b`, and `c` -- `Eigen::Quaternion` mostly behaves "as-if" it was a 3x3 rotation matrix). Multiplying quaternions by quaternions is cheaper than 3x3 by 3x3 matrices. Also converting back to angle-axis is cheaper from quaternions. But, e.g., if you need to multiply more than one vector by the rotation, it is actually cheaper to first convert the quaternion to a 3x3 matrix.